# CUDA - Confusion about the Visual Profiler results of “branch” and “divergent branch” (2)

Tags: linux, cuda, profiler

I use NVIDIA Visual Profiler to analyze my code. The test kernels are:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Group 1
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_0(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid < 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid;
    }
}
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_1(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid == 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid;
    }
}
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_2(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid >= 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid;
    }
}
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_3(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid > 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid;
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Group 2
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_4(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid < 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid + 1;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid + 2;
    }
}
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_5(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid == 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid + 1;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid + 2;
    }
}
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_6(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid >= 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid + 1;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid + 2;
    }
}
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_7(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid > 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid + 1;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid + 2;
    }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Group 3
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_8(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid < 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid + 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid + 2.0;
    }
}
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_9(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid == 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid + 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid + 2.0;
    }
}
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_10(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid >= 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid + 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid + 2.0;
    }
}
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_11(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid > 0)
    {
         a[tid] = tid + 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
         b[tid] = tid + 2.0;
    }
}
```

When I launched the test kernels with <<< 1, 32 >>>, I got the results from profiler like this:

```
gpu_test_divergency_0 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 1 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_1 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 1 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_2 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 1 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_3 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 1 divergent branch = 0

gpu_test_divergency_4 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 3 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_5 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 3 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_6 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 2 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_7 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 3 divergent branch = 0

gpu_test_divergency_8 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 3 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_9 :  Branch Efficiency = 75%  branch = 4 divergent branch = 1
gpu_test_divergency_10 : Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 2 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_11 : Branch Efficiency = 75%  branch = 4 divergent branch = 1
```

And when I launched the test kernels with <<< 1, 64 >>>, I got the results from profiler like this:

```
gpu_test_divergency_0 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 2 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_1 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 2 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_2 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 2 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_3 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 2 divergent branch = 0

gpu_test_divergency_4 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 6 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_5 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 6 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_6 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 4 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_7 :  Branch Efficiency = 100% branch = 5 divergent branch = 0

gpu_test_divergency_8 :  Branch Efficiency = 100%  branch = 6 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_9 :  Branch Efficiency = 85.7% branch = 7 divergent branch = 1
gpu_test_divergency_10 : Branch Efficiency = 100%  branch = 4 divergent branch = 0
gpu_test_divergency_11 : Branch Efficiency = 83.3% branch = 6 divergent branch = 1
```

I use "GeForce GTX 570" with the CUDA Capability of 2.0 and NVIDIA Visual Profiler v4.2 on Linux. According to the documents:

*"branch" - "Number of branches taken by threads executing a kernel. This counter will be incremented by one if at least one thread in a warp takes the branch."*

*"divergent branch" - "Number of divergent branches within a warp. This counter will be incremented by one if at least one tread in a warp diverges (that is, follows a different execution path) via a data dependent conditional branch."*

But I am really confused about the results. Why the numbers of "branch" for each test group are different? And why only the third test group seems to have the right "divergent branch"?

@JackOLantern: I compiled in release mode. I disassembled it in your way. The results of "gpu_test_divergency_4" is exactly the same as yours but the result of "gpu_test_divergency_0" is different:

```
    Function : _Z21gpu_test_divergency_0PfS_
/*0000*/     /*0x00005de428004404*/     MOV R1, c [0x1] [0x100];
/*0008*/     /*0x94001c042c000000*/     S2R R0, SR_CTAid_X;
/*0010*/     /*0x84009c042c000000*/     S2R R2, SR_Tid_X;
/*0018*/     /*0x20009ca320044000*/     IMAD R2, R0, c [0x0] [0x8], R2;
/*0020*/     /*0xfc21dc23188e0000*/     ISETP.LT.AND P0, pt, R2, RZ, pt;
/*0028*/     /*0x0920de0418000000*/     I2F.F32.S32 R3, R2;
/*0030*/     /*0x9020204340004000*/     @!P0 ISCADD R0, R2, c [0x0] [0x24], 0x2;
/*0038*/     /*0x8020804340004000*/     @P0 ISCADD R2, R2, c [0x0] [0x20], 0x2;
/*0040*/     /*0x0000e08590000000*/     @!P0 ST [R0], R3;
/*0048*/     /*0x0020c08590000000*/     @P0 ST [R2], R3;
/*0050*/     /*0x00001de780000000*/     EXIT;
```

I guess, like you said, conversion instructions (I2F in this case) do not add extra branch.

But I cannot see the relationship between these disassembled code and the Profiler results. I learned from another post (https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/463316/branch-divergent-branches/) that divergent branch is calculated with the actual thread(warp) running situation on SMs. So I guess we cannot deduce the branch divergence of each actual running, just according to these disassembled code. Am I right?

Comment: Type cast could introduce extra branch.

Comment: @Eric It seems that type casting does not add any extra branch, see the disassemblies in my answer below.

Comment: @Eric: I agree with JackOLantern

Answer (score 1):

**FOLLOW UP - USING VOTE INTRINSICS TO CHECK THREAD DIVERGENCE**

I think the best way to check about thread divergence within warps is using vote intrinsics and in particular the `__ballot` and `__popc` intrinsics. A good explanation on `__ballot` and `__popc` is available in the book by Shane Cook, CUDA Programming, Morgan Kaufmann.

The prototype of `__ballot` is the following

```
unsigned int __ballot(int predicate);
```

If predicate is nonzero, `__ballot` returns a value with the `N`th bit set, where `N` is `threadIdx.x`.

On the other side, `__popc` returns the number of bits set withing a `32`-bit parameter.

So, by jointly using `__ballot`, `__popc` and `atomicAdd`, one can check if a warp is divergent or not.

To this end, I have set up the following code

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__device__ unsigned int __ballot_non_atom(int predicate)
{
    if (predicate != 0) return (1 << (threadIdx.x % 32));
    else return 0;
}

__global__ void gpu_test_divergency_0(unsigned int* d_ballot, int Num_Warps_per_Block)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    const unsigned int warp_num = threadIdx.x >> 5;

    atomicAdd(&d_ballot[warp_num+blockIdx.x*Num_Warps_per_Block],__popc(__ballot_non_atom(tid > 2)));
    //  atomicAdd(&d_ballot[warp_num+blockIdx.x*Num_Warps_per_Block],__popc(__ballot(tid > 2)));

}

#include <conio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int Num_Threads_per_Block      = 64;
    unsigned int Num_Blocks_per_Grid        = 1;
    unsigned int Num_Warps_per_Block        = Num_Threads_per_Block/32;
    unsigned int Num_Warps_per_Grid         = (Num_Threads_per_Block*Num_Blocks_per_Grid)/32;

    unsigned int* h_ballot = (unsigned int*)malloc(Num_Warps_per_Grid*sizeof(unsigned int));
    unsigned int* d_ballot; cudaMalloc((void**)&d_ballot, Num_Warps_per_Grid*sizeof(unsigned int));

    for (int i=0; i<Num_Warps_per_Grid; i++) h_ballot[i] = 0;

    cudaMemcpy(d_ballot, h_ballot, Num_Warps_per_Grid*sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    gpu_test_divergency_0<<<Num_Blocks_per_Grid,Num_Threads_per_Block>>>(d_ballot,Num_Warps_per_Block);

    cudaMemcpy(h_ballot, d_ballot, Num_Warps_per_Grid*sizeof(unsigned int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i=0; i<Num_Warps_per_Grid; i++) { 
        if ((h_ballot[i] == 0)||(h_ballot[i] == 32)) std::cout << "Warp " << i << " IS NOT divergent- Predicate true for " << h_ballot[i] << " threads\n";
            else std::cout << "Warp " << i << " IS divergent - Predicate true for " << h_ballot[i] << " threads\n";
    }

    getch();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please, note that I'm right now running the code on a compute capability 1.2 card, so in the example above I'm using `__ballot_non_atom` which is a non-intrinsic equivalent to `__ballot`, since `__ballot` is available only for compute capability >= 2.0. In other words, if you have a card with compute capability >= 2.0, please uncommented the instruction using `__ballot` in the kernel function.

With the above code, you can play with all your kernel functions above by simply changing the relevant predicate in the kernel function.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

I compiled your code for a compute capability `2.0` under **release** mode and I used `-keep` to retain intermediate files and the `cuobjdump` utility to produce the disassembly of two of your kernels, namely:

```
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_0(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid < 0) a[tid] = tid;
    else b[tid] = tid;
}
```

and

```
static __global__ void gpu_test_divergency_4(float *a, float *b)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tid < 0) a[tid] = tid + 1;
    else b[tid] = tid + 2;
}
```

The results are the following

```
gpu_test_divergency_0

/*0000*/        MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];                 /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
/*0008*/        S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;                    /* 0x2c00000094001c04 */
/*0010*/        S2R R2, SR_TID.X;                      /* 0x2c00000084009c04 */
/*0018*/        IMAD R2, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;          /* 0x2004400020009ca3 */
/*0020*/        ISETP.LT.AND P0, PT, R2, RZ, PT;       /* 0x188e0000fc21dc23 */
/*0028*/        I2F.F32.S32 R0, R2;                    /* 0x1800000009201e04 */
/*0030*/   @!P0 ISCADD R3, R2, c[0x0][0x24], 0x2;      /* 0x400040009020e043 */
/*0038*/    @P0 ISCADD R2, R2, c[0x0][0x20], 0x2;      /* 0x4000400080208043 */
/*0040*/   @!P0 ST [R3], R0;                           /* 0x9000000000302085 */
/*0048*/    @P0 ST [R2], R0;                           /* 0x9000000000200085 */
/*0050*/        EXIT ;                                 /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
```

and

```
gpu_test_divergency_4

/*0000*/        MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];                 /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
/*0008*/        S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;                    /* 0x2c00000094001c04 */   R0 = BlockIdx.x
/*0010*/        S2R R2, SR_TID.X;                      /* 0x2c00000084009c04 */   R2 = ThreadIdx.x
/*0018*/        IMAD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;          /* 0x2004400020001ca3 */   R0 = R0 * c + R2
/*0020*/        ISETP.LT.AND P0, PT, R0, RZ, PT;       /* 0x188e0000fc01dc23 */   If statement
/*0028*/    @P0 BRA.U 0x58;                            /* 0x40000000a00081e7 */   Branch 1 - Jump to 0x58
/*0030*/   @!P0 IADD R2, R0, 0x2;                      /* 0x4800c0000800a003 */   Branch 2 - R2 = R0 + 2
/*0038*/   @!P0 ISCADD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x24], 0x2;      /* 0x4000400090002043 */   Branch 2 - Calculate gmem address
/*0040*/   @!P0 I2F.F32.S32 R2, R2;                    /* 0x180000000920a204 */   Branch 2 - R2 = R2 after int to float cast
/*0048*/   @!P0 ST [R0], R2;                           /* 0x900000000000a085 */   Branch 2 - gmem store
/*0050*/   @!P0 BRA.U 0x78;                            /* 0x400000008000a1e7 */   Branch 2 - Jump to 0x78 (exit)
/*0058*/    @P0 IADD R2, R0, 0x1;                      /* 0x4800c00004008003 */   Branch 1 - R2 = R0 + 1
/*0060*/    @P0 ISCADD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x20], 0x2;      /* 0x4000400080000043 */   Branch 1 - Calculate gmem address
/*0068*/    @P0 I2F.F32.S32 R2, R2;                    /* 0x1800000009208204 */   Branch 1 - R2 = R2 after int to float cast
/*0070*/    @P0 ST [R0], R2;                           /* 0x9000000000008085 */   Branch 1 - gmem store
/*0078*/        EXIT ;                                 /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
```

From the above disassemblies, I would expect that the results of your branch divergency tests be the same.

Are you compiling in a debug or release mode?

Comment: @Ben Please, see my revised answer. Concerning the disassembled code for the "`0`" case, you are right, it is different from that for the "`4`" case. I made a mistake and I have edited my answer. However, please have a look at the first part. I'm providing a code based on vote intrinsics by which you could check about thread divergence in a generic code. The vote intrinsics instructions in the kernel functions can be added to any kernel to evaluate thread divergence. I'm not aware of the criterion used by the Visual Profiler and I have not replicated your result by that tool.