# 'ballot' behavior on inactive lanes

Tags: cuda

Warp voting functions can be invoked within a diverging branch and its effects are considered only among active threads. However, I am unsure how `ballot` works in that case? Are inactive threads always contributing 0? Or maybe the result is undefined?

---

Similar question: [Do warp vote functions synchronize threads in the warp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441270/do-warp-vote-functions-synchronize-threads-in-the-warp/19442278)

One answer quotes PTX ISA, which contains a sentence

> In the ballot form, vote.ballot.b32 simply copies the predicate from
>   each thread in a warp into the corresponding bit position of
>   destination register d, where the bit position corresponds to the
>   thread's lane id.

but it does not explain how inactive threads are treated.

Comment: Would constructing an example similar to that in the answer to [CUDA - Confusion about the Visual Profiler results of “branch” and “divergent branch” (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334589/cuda-confusion-about-the-visual-profiler-results-of-branch-and-divergent-br/19351054#19351054) help you answer the question? I would say that inactive threads can be associated to a "false" predicate, while active threads to a "true" predicate?

Comment: An example is nice, but what I am concerned is if we have a guarantee about the `ballot` behavior, and not an undefined behavior which just happens to work as expected now and may fail in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions):

> For each of these warp vote operations, the result excludes threads that are inactive (e.g., due to warp divergence). Inactive threads are represented by 0 bits in the value returned by __ballot() and are not considered in the reductions performed by __all() and __any().

Comment: Somehow I missed that when reading documentation myself... thank you!